# Eval inline ruby inside a markdown document

Tags: ruby, markdown, inline-code

I need to call some helpers from a Markdown view. Is this somehow a good practice and is generally supported on popular ruby-based Markdown parsers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it isn't. Markdown is a standardized, text-focused, cross-language format and the most of Markdown parsers offers support for the standard syntax.

However, platforms that need advanced features, such as wiki and [GitHub](http://github.com/github/github-flavored-markdown), adds custom features. Common features, are tags to generate page TOC based on the document structure.

AFAIK, not BlueCloth nor RDiscount offers built-in support for extensions. You would have to code them yourself before passing the markdown text to processor.

Answer (score 0):

Extending the class to handle new tags or syntax is not a bad idea, but eval'ing inline ruby code from a possibly untrusted source is an absolutely horrible idea!

Comment: well it's for my blog, I'll be the only one writing :) Any reference on how to extend markdown syntax for Bluecloth or any other ruby gem?